# prefetch_related for Authenticated user

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a django web application and i'm in the process of minimizing the amount of individual database hits by using the `prefetch_related` and `select_related` methods, i have a certain method in my `User` model that pulls a couple of different related objects from it.

```
def get_profile_info(self):
    *fetch data from a couple of models*
```

And then i use this method in my `view`.

```
def profile(request):
    profile_info = request.user.get_profile_info()
    *rest of the view*
```

The problem is, since `request.user` is not retrieved by the normal query methods, i don't get to use the `prefetch_related` and `select_related` along with pulling the user, and i can't find any way to retrieve the related data along with the model of that user.

Is there a way to, say, override the retrieving of the user model so i can run the `prefetch_related` and `select_related` methods?

Comment: `The problem is, since request.user is not retrieved by the normal query methods,` can you please explain this?

Comment: Normally, to retrieve a django model, you create a query like:
Model.objects.get(*query*)
And for the request.user, it simply gets the User model when you call request.user in the view.
And the `prefetch_related` and `select_related` are usable in the .objects methods of the models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always refetch the user from the database using `select_related` and `prefetch_related`. If `select_related` and `prefetch_related` save a lot of queries, then it will be worth the extra query to fetch the user.

```
def profile(request):
    user = User.objects.select_related(
        ...
    ).prefetch_related(
        ...
    ).get(pk=request.user.pk)
```

Note that depending on the view, `prefetch_related` might not be very useful in this case. It causes one extra query per model, so it's most useful when you are fetching the related objects for an entire queryset, not a single object.

Comment: That's what i was considering doing, but it just felt wrong and i felt like there would be a more efficient way :(

Comment: This has been downvoted a couple of times so I thought I'd add a comment. @Aver's answer prevents any duplicate queries, so should probably be accepted. However Aver's answer means that fetching the user is a slightly more expensive query in *every* view. If you only use the related profile in the `profile` view, then it might be pragmatic to use my answer. So I'm going to leave my answer rather than deleting it. In practice, I don't think you'll see a measurable difference between both answers - it's n+1 queries that kill performance in Django, not a single query or extra join.

Answer (score 28):

Sorry for this necroposting, but this theme is so important and really simple answer exists, just create a custom manager for your user model and override the `get` method with `select_related` like this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager


class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().select_related('<put fields that you want>').get(*args, **kwargs)


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ...

    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

Now, whenever Django will retrieve user instance for `request.user`, it will be using this manager. Also all your `CustomUser.objects.get()` queries will select specified related fields too.

Comment: This is indeed the better approach

Comment: This was a super simple solution to a big optimization issue on my end with user groups. Thanks!

Comment: How many years have I been thinking about a solution for this. Simple elegant Pythonic

Comment: This requires a ton of work to replace the AUTH_USER model with a custom one. no easy task, and must be done before basically any other work. so if you are far down your development using the default model, this does not work.

Answer (score 3):

A more granual way could be using a custom authentication backend. By using this approach one will be able to use UserModel.objects.get without the drawback of making unnecessary joins(.select_related()) or DB lookups(.prefetch_related()) while using this manager in other segments of code.

```
# auth_backends.py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend


UserModel = get_user_model()


class RelatedModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        if username is None:
            username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        if username is None or password is None:
            return
        try:
            user = UserModel._default_manager.select_related(
                ...  # Do your magic here
            ).prefetch_related(
                ...  # Do your magic here
            )
            get(
                **{UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD: username}
            )
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a nonexistent user (#20760).
            UserModel().set_password(password)
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = UserModel._default_manager.select_related(
                ...  # Do your magic here
            ).prefetch_related(
                ...  # Do your magic here
            ).get(pk=user_id)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        return user if self.user_can_authenticate(user) else None
```

Now we need to add new backend into settings file, read more about custom auth backends [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends)

```
# settings.py
...
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['myproject.auth_backends.RelatedModelBackend']
...
```

Comment: This is much closer to the actual, quickest answer when using the default user model.
Overly complex, as one only has to override the `def get_ser` portion. the other authenticate portion is only used on login.